# How can I get optimistic concurrency with JPA annotation

Tags: optimistic-locking

I am using JPA 3, with annotation (no mapping file) and with provider org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence

I need to have optimistic concurrency.

1)I tried to rely on the tag called , it did not work.

2)
So I decided to do it with java code. I have a mergeServiceRequest method and an object with type Request as follows: I start a transaction, lock the request object, 
then try to get a Request object newRequest from database, compare its timestamp with the current one request. If they do not match, I throw an exception; if they match, then I update the current request `enter code here`with current time and save it to database.

I need to lock the object manually, because by starting a transaction from session, it does not put a lock on the row in database. I wrote some java code which shows that a transaction does not lock the record in database automatically.

Problem with this approach is the query

```
Request newRequest=entityManager.createQuery("select r  from Request r where serviceRequestId =  " + request.getServiceRequestId());
```

always return same object as request. "request" is in the session entityManger, and the query always return what is cached in the session. I tried all the five query.setHint lines and I still get same result: no database query is performed, the result is from session cache directly.

```
@Transactional
    public void mergeServiceRequest(Request request) {
        System.out.println("ServiceRequestDao.java line 209");
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        entityManager.lock(request, LockModeType.WRITE); // use to lock the database row

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select r  from Request r where serviceRequestId =  " + request.getServiceRequestId());
        //query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", "BYPASS");
        //query.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheMode", CacheMode.REFRESH);
        //query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheMode.REFRESH);
        //query.setHint("javax.persistence.retrieveMode", CacheMode.REFRESH);
        //query.setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache);

        Request newRequest=(Request)query.getSingleResult();


        if (! newRequest.getLastUpdatedOn().equals(request.getLastUpdatedOn())) {
            throw new StaleObjectStateException(request.getClass().toString(), request.getServiceRequestId());
        }

        request.setLastUpdatedOn(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));     
        entityManager.persist(request);
        entityManager.flush();      
        transaction.commit();   
    }
```

3)So I also tried to use another session get query the newRequest, if I do that, the newRequest will be different from request. But for some reason, if I do that, then the lock on request object is never released, even after the transaction commit. Code looks like below

```
@Transactional
    public void mergeServiceRequest(Request request) {
        System.out.println("ServiceRequestDao.java line 209");
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        entityManager.lock(request, LockModeType.WRITE); // use to lock the database row

        Request newRequest=findRequest(request.getServiceRequestId()); // get it from another session                   

        if (! newRequest.getLastUpdatedOn().equals(request.getLastUpdatedOn())) {
            throw new StaleObjectStateException(request.getClass().toString(), request.getServiceRequestId());
        }

        request.setLastUpdatedOn(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));     
        entityManager.persist(request);
        entityManager.flush();      
        transaction.commit();   
//lock on the database record is not released after this, and even after entityManager is closed
    }
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Daniel